# Focus back on input after click button

Tags: jquery, onclick, eventtrigger, onblur, onfocus

So I have an input text and a button. When I focus on the input and I click on the button next, I want the button to do some stuff (like clearing the input value) then focus back on the input. (And I have a blur event doing some stuff too)

I've been trying a `$('input').focus();` inside my `$('button').on("mousedown", function() {});` but it doesn't work

**EDIT : Sorry for the answer I've been posting, I'm new on the StackOverflow !**
Here is what I've been trying with your code and my blur event. But it's not working ! How can I make it work please ?

```js
var button = $("button");
button.on("click", function(){
  var name = $("#name")
  name.val("");
  name.focus();
});

$("input").on("blur", function(e){
  button.hide();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("input").focus(function(){
  button.show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off">
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: That statement would try to put focus on a all inputs in the document, which obviously isn't a good idea. Use a more specific selector.

Comment: The problem you're facing is that you can't click the button once you put your name in the textbox. Because of your blur function, the button is gone before you can click it. Why do you want your button to disappear?

Comment: Thank you for explaining me the real behaviour of the blur event. I want my button to disappear when I lose focus on the input except when I click on the button. I know it's a bit of a conflict because clicking on a button means exiting the input focus. I wondered if focusout do solve this problem ? Or is there any way to make the button be part of the input focus ? I don't know :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example of what you can do to clear and then focus your input. I would advise you, however, to specify the element by id if you're planning to focus it as otherwise, you're essentially trying to focus all inputs.

```js
var button = $("button");
button.click(function(){
    var name = $("#name")
    name.val("");
    name.focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off">
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Is there any way to make it work with a _mousedown_ event ? I have a onblur event handler hiding the button when exiting the input focus. I've been thinking on using _stopPropagation()_ inside my click/mousedown event... Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to click event and then focus on input tag.

```
$('button').on("click", function() {
    $('input').focus();
});
```